# Installing Opencpu via apt-get install, not working

Tags: opencpu

I just ran an apt-get install, and this is the output I get.

```
$ sudo apt-get install opencpu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package opencpu
```

Anybody else run into problems installing opencpu in Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS)?

Comment: This probably shouldn't have the [r] tag, nor the [statistics] tag, and it also probably would be better suited to SuperUser, or maybe even Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no package called "opencpu" in Ubuntu proper: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=opencpu Did you follow the specific instructions here: https://www.opencpu.org/download.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `opencpu-1.5` ppa repository first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opencpu/opencpu-1.5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opencpu
```

Have a look at the [server manual](http://jeroenooms.github.com/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf) for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks so much Jeroen!!! It did it! I did not look at the server manual in detail, thanks for pointing me in this direction. P